# Error loading java.awt.font in Eclipse Android project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've seen a few places where this was asked but I haven't seen where it's been resolved.

I've just installed the tools needed to develop Android applications. This includes, of course, Eclipse. When I try to open the res/main.xml file, I get the error 'could not initialize class java.awt.font'.

I'm running the newest version of Eclipse and all the software required for Android development. I'm running on Ubuntu 10.04 32bit.

Sun JDK and JRE are installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click on the XML file in the package explorer (your navigation pane) and go to "Open With" and then "XML Editor".

From that point, if you just want to look at the code, just above where eclipse puts the "Console" tab (nearer to the bottom of the eclipse window), you should see a small tab, which says "Source". Clicking on that will get you the pure code in the XML file.